# How to set canView in Silverstripe for public website vs CMS

Tags: php, silverstripe

We have a custom extension on our Member class in a Silverstripe project:

```
public function canView($member = null) {
    if ($this->Link() && $this->isPublished()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is so member details can only be viewed if they are specifically published via `$this->isPublished() == true`.

This method has been working fine but a recent upgrade to Silverstripe 3.6.1 seems to have broken it. CMS administrators can no longer create new Members (returns a 403/ Forbidden error) unless canView is overwritten to "true":

```
public function canView($member = null) {
   return true;
}
```

How can I set it up so:

1. In the public website Member details can only be viewed if
   `$this->isPublished() == true`
2. In the CMS all Members details can be viewed by a user with
       Administrator permissions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're implementing permission methods in Extensions, you can return either:

- `true` : grant the permission
- `false` : deny the permission
- `null` : Don't influence the permission (eg. other extensions or the base methods of the DataObject will come into play)

In your case, returning `false` seems wrong, because you deny viewing of the Object if the first condition isn't met. That means, that an Administrator won't be able to see the object in the CMS in these cases, which he clearly should.

The correct way to implement this would be something like:

```
public function canView($member = null) {
    if ($this->Link() && $this->isPublished()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // fall back to default permissions
        return null;
    }
}
```